# Partial xml response from web service via ksoap2

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I'm new in both Android and Java (use to develop in C# before) and I'm quite desperate on this. I'm using ksoap2 to contact a .NET Web Service to get xml data. My code is simple and it works well if the xml is small:

```
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
String xmlResponse = response.toString();
```

this is a simple way to get the response, which is a simple xml string. But when the xml is large, it gets truncate, and I suppose it is because the response is kept in memory. I read some other people having this problem, but I didn't find a solution that really helps me; probably I miss the necessary knowledge to manage the question, and this is confirmed by the fact that navigating the variables on Eclipse I found that the data is fully there, I only did't know how to reach it... can somebody help me? how can i get the missing part of the response? I need to save the response locally? Need to cycle an InputStream? help, please...

Comment: When you say "data is fully there*, where is it?

Comment: when debugging on Eclipse, navigating through the variable "soapEnvelope" i see in BodyIn -> SoapPrimitive -> value that the data is truncate, but explorating a little more on "value" property there is an array of vectors like [0-99999] where each cell contain a byte of the response; the last of this bytes is the last byte of the full response, which I don't know how, ehm, "to reach" (sorry for the bad english)...

Comment: Eclipse truncates data in the debugger view. It is still all there for your program to access. Perhaps you can print the xmlResponse string to assure yourself.

Comment: I still have to parse xmlResponse with sax - are you saying I will find all the data in there? I can't check it right now, but if what you say it's true I'll made you know and give you a "solved" tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debugger windows Eclipse will not show all the array elements. If you are able to see them all when you expand the array then they are all there for your program to use.

<strike>If you are suspecting large response, SAX is the right way to parse it</strike>

EDIT:
As Manfred explains [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586880/partial-xml-response-from-web-service-via-ksoap2/7602105#7602105), `response.toString()` is a bad idea because KSoap has already done the parsing.

Comment: This is a bad idea since KSoap already parsed it for you and are basically parsing it twice.

Comment: @Manfred I assume you are referring to my comment about SAX parsing? I probably shouldn't have written it. My core answer was to OP's question how to access data when Eclipse shows partial result in summary view but when expanded it shows everything; the answer was program needs to do nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the getResponse method of the envelope and parse the SoapObject tree for whatever you need. Using bodyIn and parsing that with SAX adds a second parsing.. if you do that you might as well not use ksoap2.

Comment: Correct. At this stage it is already parsed into SoapObjects.. if you do toString and the parse it you are just parsing twice..

Comment: interesting, and in fact I will parse the response after the response.toString(); but the xml represents a complex object, so I need to populate it with values inside the xml - how am I supposed to do then? more specifically, how i can iterate nodes and elements inside soapobjects? could you post an exampe please?

Comment: There is lots of documentation on the wiki of the ksoap2-android project along those lines. Read there e.g. http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks and btw. I am the project owner and we do have a mailing list as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, very useful info. I would live to give a thumbs up to both of you, but I still cant't... thanks anyway...